# Can an Endpoint call severals backend services on cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run

How can have one endpoint but this call several backend services (several cloud run services) ?. Thanks.

I want to have one endpoint that call several cloud run endpoints... how i do that?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Cloud Run provides you with an endpoint that will invoke as many Cloud Run services as required/allowed to handle the traffic. If you mean that you want to route traffic to different services based upon URL, no. However, add more details to your question to make clear what you want.

Comment: I want to have one endpoint that call several cloud run endpoints... how i do that? Do you have a link??

Comment: Cloud Run will autoscale but does not distribute traffic based upon path routing. You will need to choose a different service or implement that feature yourself in one of the Cloud Run services. Refer to the options by Steren's answer. Note: I am still not sure what you exactly want from your question and your comment. Invest the time to create a good question so that you get a good answer.

Comment: You can check the article [Getting Started with Endpoints for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run) in the official GCP documentation for a reference to set up Cloud Endpoints for Cloud Run.

Comment: @JohnHanley reads Steren's answer for you to learn ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not directly possible to have multiple Cloud Run services under the same endpoint URL.

Here are a few options possible using Cloud Run and other products:

- Create a "router" Cloud Run service, that will route request to other Cloud Run services depending on the URL path.
- Use [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) to provide URL based routing
- Use [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) in front of your Cloud Run services.
- In the future, it will be possible to use [Google Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/) with Cloud Run, and use its [URL Maps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map) feature.

Comment: How is the use the Cloud Endpoints for this?? Do you have a example?. Only a endpoint to several backends cloud run.

Answer (score 0):

@steren I guess what he is asking is about congregate response for microservices. I do think, correct if I am wrong please, what he wants to know is how use cloud endpoints in front of a cloud run project(multiple independent microservices, each with its own api), and create a external visible endpoint made with multiple calls to the micro services. 
To be clear, let’s make an example:

- Cloud run service 1 -> crud user api
- Cloud run service 2 -> crud product api
- Cloud endpoint external visible api -> get user from service 1, and after get products from service 2 and return the combined response all green products for user Jane Doe.

Maybe use a cloud function to make the aggregate response, and expose it with endpoints. I don’t think otherwise you have the ability to combine the response directly in cloud endpoints.

Please correct me guys if I am wrong, I am not really sure that what I said is completely correct (I just assumed that in order to keep each microservice totally independent from the other micro services, you need to rely on an extra function or on an extra service, and you cannot directly built the combined response in the endpoints).